# python list scope across recursive call

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I wrote a recursive permutation generator in python3:

```
    def permute(self, nums):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :rtype: List[List[int]]
    """

    ret = []
    n = len(nums)
    def dfs(temp, visited):
        if len(temp) == n:
            ret.append(temp[:])
            return
        for i in range(n):
            if not visited[i]:
                visited[i] = True
                temp.append(nums[i])
                dfs(temp, visited)
                # Cannot be:
                # temp = temp[:-1]
                del temp[-1]
                visited[i] = False
    dfs([], [False for _ in range(n)])                            
    return ret
```

I originally used `temp = temp[:-1]` after the recursive dfs returned but that does not seem to work. Explicitly using `del temp[-1]` worked.

I can't figure out why this is the case, could anyway please explain?

Comment: Can you fix the indentation in your code block ? Please update the question with sample input, expected output, and actual output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning to a local variable inside a function has no effect on the outside world:

```
def foo(lst):
    lst = [1, 2, 3]

L = [1]
foo(L)
print(L)  # still [1]
```

Modifying a passed in variable does:

```
def foo(lst):
    lst.append(4)

L = [1]
foo(L)
print(L)  # [1, 4]
```

In your case, `del temp[-1]` changes the list that is being passed around. In your code there is only ever one list that is assigned to `temp`, which starts out as `[]`. `temp = temp[:-1]` creates a new independent list.